# I don't know why original list changes when alias of list is changed

Tags: python, list

`lCopy` is an alias of the original list `l`. When `lCopy` is changed, `l` also changes. I don't know why this is happening.

```
def organizingContainers(l):

    ball = 0

    def checkContainers(ball,lCopy):
        print(ball,lCopy,orig)
        while ball<len(lCopy):
            for i,j in enumerate(lCopy):
                print(lCopy,j,ball,j[ball],sum([x[ball] for x in lCopy if x is not lCopy[i]]))
                if j[ball]==sum([x[ball] for x in lCopy if x is not lCopy[i]]):
                    for sl in lCopy:
                        sl[ball]=0
                    print('l',l,'lCopy',lCopy)
                else:
                    continue
            ball+=1
        return lCopy    

    while True:
        print('ball',ball,'l',l)
        lCopy=l[:]
        newL = checkContainers(ball,lCopy)
        print('newL',newL,'l',l,'lCopy',l, 'orig',orig)
        for sL in newL:
            if set(sL)!={0} and ball<len(newL):
                ball+=1            
                break
            elif ball==len(newL):
                return True             

print(organizingContainers ([[0, 2, 1],[1, 1, 1],[2, 0, 0]]))
```

Comment: https://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html

Comment: `lCopy` is not an alias of `l`; the two are distinct list objects. Both lists, though, contain the same *references*, because `lCopy` is a *shallow* copy of `l`.

Answer (score 2):

Like @chepner was mentioning, you only made a shallow copy of `l`, you need to make a deep copy instead:

```
from copy import deepcopy
...
lCopy = deepcopy(l)
```

Answer (score 1):

As @chepner commented, this is happening because `lCopy` is not an alias of `l`. You can check it yourself using few lines, as seen bellow.

```
l = [1,2,3]
lCopy = l
lCopy.append(4)
print(l) #Will give [1,2,3,4]
```

To understand better what is happening you can create another list object `u`

```
u = [4,5,6]
lCopy = u
print(lCopy) #Will give [4,5,6]
print(l) #Will still give [1,2,3,4]
```

When you made `lCopy = u` , you simply changed the reference contained in `lCopy` to `u` instead of `l`.

As a result `lCopy` is not a copy of `l`. To be able to modify `lCopy` without having side effects to `l`, you can use deepcopy, as mentioned by @DaichiJameson.